# Apply hstack on an array of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of matrices `matrices_w` I want to apply the `np.hstack` function on each matrix:

```py
matrices_w = np.asarray([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[9,8,7],[6,5,4]]])
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4]]])
```

such that the desired result is given by:

```py
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]])
```

So far I have tried several functions including `np.apply_along_axis` but could not get things to work.

Comment: No stacking required, just reshape: `matrices_w.reshape(matrices_w.shape[0], -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `reshape` is easiest and fastest way.  But it may be worth while figuring out why `hstack` does not work.

```
In [192]: arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[9,8,7],[6,5,4]]])
```

`hstack` runs, but produces a different order:

```
In [193]: np.hstack(arr)                                                     
Out[193]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4]])
```

that's because `hstack` treats the first dimension of the array as a list, and joins the two arrays:

```
In [194]: np.concatenate([arr[0],arr[1]], axis=-1)                           
Out[194]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4]])
```

If we split it into lists on the 2nd dimension we get the order you want:

```
In [195]: np.concatenate([arr[:,0],arr[:,1]], axis=-1)                       
Out[195]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]])
```